# SQL QUALIFY equivalent HIVE query

Tags: sql, hive, oracle-sqldeveloper, hiveql, row-number

I'm trying to create a `HIVE query` from an `Oracle SQL query`. Essentially I want to select the first record, sorted `descending` by `UPDATED_TM, DATETIME, ID_NUM`.

```
SELECT 
  tbl1.NUM AS ID,
  tbl1.UNIT AS UNIT,  
  tbl2.VALUE AS VALUE,
  tbl1.CONTACT AS CONTACT_NAME,
  'FILE' AS SOURCE,
  CURDATE() AS DATE
FROM
  DB1.TBL1 tbl1
  LEFT JOIN DB1.TBL2 tbl2 ON tbl1.USR_ID = tbl2.USR_ID
WHERE
  tbl1.UNIT IS NOT NULL
  AND tbl1.TYPE = 'Generic'
QUALIFY 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tbl1.ROW_ID ORDER BY tbl1.UPDATED_TM DESC, tbl1.DATETIME DESC, tbl1.ID_NUM DESC) = 1
```

And my attempt at an equivalent `Hive query` (but also sql-compatible):

```
SELECT 
  tbl1.NUM AS ID,
  tbl1.UNIT AS UNIT,  
  tbl2.VALUE AS VALUE,
  tbl1.CONTACT AS CONTACT_NAME,
  'FILE' AS SOURCE,
  CURDATE() AS DATE
FROM (
  SELECT 
    USR_ID, TYPE, NUM, UNIT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tbl1.ROW_ID ORDER BY tbl1.UPDATED_TM DESC, tbl1.DATETIME DESC, tbl1.ID_NUM DESC) AS RNUM
  FROM 
    DB1.TBL1
  ) tbl1
  LEFT JOIN DB1.TBL2 tbl2 ON tbl1.USR_ID = tbl2.USR_ID
WHERE
  tbl1.RNUM = 1
  AND tbl1.UNIT IS NOT NULL
  AND tbl1.TYPE = 'Generic'
```

Does that seem correct? Is there any way I can optimize the query? The tables I'm working with are quite large and I would like to make this as efficient as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT 
  tbl1.NUM AS ID,
  tbl1.UNIT AS UNIT,  
  tbl2.VALUE AS VALUE,
  tbl1.CONTACT AS CONTACT_NAME,
  'FILE' AS SOURCE,
  CURDATE() AS DATE
FROM
(
SELECT 
    USR_ID, TYPE, NUM, UNIT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tbl.ROW_ID ORDER BY tbl.UPDATED_TM DESC, tbl.DATETIME DESC, tbl.ID_NUM DESC) AS RNUM
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
                USR_ID,TYPE,NUM,UNIT,ROW_ID,UPDATED_TM,DATETIME,ID_NUM 
            FROM DB1.TBL1
        WHERE UNIT IS NOT NULL 
        AND TYPE = 'Generic'
    )tbl
)tbl1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
DB1.TBL2 tbl2
ON tbl1.USR_ID = tbl2.USR_ID
WHERE tbl1.RNUM = 1;
```

Comment: @Ubobo: No need for the double nesting, though. You can combine the inner most SELECT with the middle-tier one (thus filtering on `UNIT` and `TYPE` and getting the row numbers on the same level).